# How to align buttons in a row of columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row of columns that consist of an image some text and a button. How can I have the button on the bottom of each of the columns look aligned.

I tried various flex box methods for example flex-end, however that messes with the rest of the content alignment. I have also used position relative for the parent and position absolute bottom 0 for the button. The the problem with that is it collides with the sibling paragraph tag that might contain a different length of text.
Example Image
!(https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e27ehcnqdsyx89/Screen%20Shot%202019-01-19%20at%2012.26.03%20PM.png?dl=0)

```
<div class="content" for number of content>
<img
/>

<div class="title">
  <h4>Title</h4>
</div>
<div class="body">
  <p>Paragraphs of various length</p>
</div>
<a>
  <button class="btn btn-default">
   CTA
  </button>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put correct html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="item__content">
      <div class="item__title"><h4>Title</h4></div>
      <div class="item__body"><p>Paragraphs of various lenthParagraphs of various lengthParagraphs of various length</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__options">
      <button class="btn btn-default">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="item__content">
      <div class="item__title"><h4>Title</h4></div>
      <div class="item__body"><p>Paragraphs of various lenthParagraphs of various lengthParagraphs of various length</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__options">
      <button class="btn btn-default">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" /></div>
    <div class="item__content">
      <div class="item__title"><h4>Title</h4></div>
      <div class="item__body"><p>Paragraphs of various lenthParagraphs of various lengthParagraphs of various length</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__options">
      <button class="btn btn-default">CTA</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .item {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }

  .item:not(last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .item__image {

  }

  .item__content {
    flex: 2 ;
  }

  .item__options {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px; 
  }
```

view the output here: https://jsfiddle.net/2467mgn5/2/

Comment: That works until you encounter a p tag that contains more or less text than the other item__bodys

Comment: Ahh yeah, I see what you mean. Hmm I am playing around with using flex within the item with flex-direction: column but that seems to have the same problem.

Comment: I think I got it, try the fiddle again. https://jsfiddle.net/2467mgn5/2/